# When we train a neural network with ExponentialMovingAverage, does the model use the decayed variable by default?

Tags: tensorflow

When we use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.apply(var) to maintains moving averages of variables, then if we update a variable such as use tf.assign, to get decayed variable, we will use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.average(var), but if we get the variable directly by tf.Session.run(var), we will get the variable without decay.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf;  

v1 = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)  
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99)  
maintain_average = ema.apply([v1])  

with tf.Session() as sess:  
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()  
    sess.run(init)  

    print(sess.run([v1, ema.average(v1)])) 
    # Out:[0.0, 0.0]

    sess.run(tf.assign(v1, 5))
    sess.run(maintain_average)  
    print(sess.run([v1, ema.average(v1)]))
    # Out: [10.0, 0.14949986]
```

So when we train a neural network with ExponentialMovingAverage, does the model default to using the decayed variable by tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage.average()?

More concrete example:

```
image_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                  [BATCH_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_CHANNELS],
                                  'image-tensor')
    label_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                  [None,10],
                                  'label-tensor')
    net_output = creat_net(image_tensor)
    #suppose creat_net() have build a neural network
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=net_output, labels=label_tensor))
    loss = cross_entropy
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_step]):
        training_op = ema.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
```

So when I run the training_op to train the network, the network will use the average at default or I need extra code to use decayed variables? In other words, GradientDescentOptimizer will use the true value or decayed value to compute loss in the next step?

Comment: 您好，您的这个问题后来有进展吗？我用了EMA之后CNN的性能也没有变好，不知道是不是根本没有用上更新的变量。我的使用方式跟你一样。

Comment: 不知道，不过我上面的第二个例子是从官网教程里改的，如果需要其它操作，官网应该不会不说，所以直接用应该没问题，我当初只是以防万一问一下，只不过没有得到想要的答案。不过我想应该不是这个的问题，你应该从别的地方找找原因。如果你还是不放心，你可以用最简单的线性函数结合梯度下降来测试一下，简单的几个参数都是可以手算的，你比较一下结果应该就能得到答案。如果你这么做了，就写篇博客什么的分享一下吧，省的后人再有同样的疑问，也让我看看，谢谢。

Comment: 目前没有计划这么去做，问了一个比较有经验的，他告诉我可以直接把 GradientDescentOptimizer 换成 AdamOptimizer。Adam有类似的moving average操作，不过可能和EMA不完全相同。

Comment: 嗯，是的。Adam跟EMA是不一样的，Adam比EMA稍微复杂一点，不过用Adam替换EMA应该是可行的。

Answer (score 0):

`v1` is a variable with its own value (`10.0` in your case).

`tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` maintains a variable inside, that gets update each time you invoke `average`.

Every time you invoke `average` with a new input, you're just computing the next time step of the exponential moving average (hence just changing the private variable of tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage op) without changing the input variables at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I have known that v1 and average are independent respectively. I'm sorry about my question is not specific enough. I will update edit my question, and write a concrete example.